# QML overlay on the camera video

Tags: qt, qml, qtmultimedia

I am trying to draw some overlay on the frame captured by the Camera objet in Qt/QML. The camera itself is defined as:

```
Camera {
    id: camera
    captureMode: Camera.CaptureVideo
}
VideoOutput {
    source: camera
    focus : visible 
    anchors.fill: parent
}
```

Now when I call `camera.videorecorder.record()`, the camera starts recording and the current frame is displayed on the video output canvas. Now, what I would like to do is draw a rectangle at some arbitrary location on the frame.

I see that there are some shader effects example (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-multimedia-video-qmlvideofx-example.html) but they look really complicated for what I want to do and I am not versed with GLSL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Camera {
    id: camera
    captureMode: Camera.CaptureVideo
}

VideoOutput {
    source: camera
    focus : visible
    anchors.fill: parent
    Rectangle {
            color: "red";
            width: parent.width / 2;
            height: parent.height / 2;
            anchors.centerIn: parent;
   }
}
```

**Edit:**
This will work too:

```
Camera {
    id: camera
    captureMode: Camera.CaptureVideo
}
VideoOutput {
    source: camera
    focus : visible
    anchors.fill: parent
}
Rectangle {
        color: "red";
        width: parent.width / 2;
        height: parent.height / 2;
        anchors.centerIn: parent;
}
```

Comment: This doesnt work for me. Ubuntu 18.04 Qt 5.9.8